# Is there any way of reading temperature without using SensorManager?

Tags: android, temperature

I have to read the environment temperature from mt app what are the ways

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of reading temperature in android without using SensorManager?

Not as part of standard Android. And even then, there is no guarantee that the device has an ambient temperature sensor.

There may be thermometers that offer USB or Bluetooth, and you could attempt to integrate with those. Of course, this would require that the user have such a piece of hardware.